# Cannot push to private github repository

Tags: git, github

An organization added me to a private repository. This repository is not owned by a normal account, I believe this is an 'organization' account with github. While I am able to clone pull and fetch, and git remote -v shows the correct url, I am still unable to **push** to the repository. The error I am getting is:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/account/project/' not found
```

I tried googling workarounds to no avail.

Is that normal? Should I be looking to any settings option from the organization's side? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think it has something to do with SSH or GPG key . Not sure though

Comment: @RohitSingh wouldn't that raise an *authorisation failure* instead?

Comment: @RohitSingh good catch! Github help says, that missing access rights (because of wrong ssh configuration) can cause the problem: https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found/

Comment: Sometimes it happens man. Once i created a new one and it worked. But i am not sure otherwise would have posted an answer

Comment: If you can pull the repository, your SSH key is working fine. It's more likely that you have been added as an collaborator with only `read` permissions.

Comment: @jdno I googled that.. but I don't seem to be able to find anything regarding read and write permissions when it comes to github private repositories? How is it possible to only give read permissions to someone on github?

Comment: These two articles hopefully point you in the right direction: [how to manage access rights on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-an-individual-s-access-to-an-organization-repository/) and [how to add outside collaborators](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-outside-collaborators-to-repositories-in-your-organization/). Both show different features where access to an organization's repositories can be configured.

Comment: It might be a private branch which is push protected.